# python: check if an email attachment is encrypted

Tags: python, excel, encryption, outlook

I am new to writing Python code and am trying to run a test to determine if an email attachment (.xls file) is encrypted with a password. I am using win32com to retrieve from Outlook and then loop through emails and attachments.

I've reviewed Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment?view=outlook-pia), but couldn't find what I need.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    email_count = inbox.Items.count
    messages = inbox.Items
    for message in messages:
                emailSendDate = message.senton.date()
                attachments = message.attachments
                emailSubject = message.Subject
                for attachment in attachments:
                    attachment_name = attachment.filename
                    #a way to test if email attachment is encrypted?
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook knows nothing about a particular attachment type - it does not know and does not care. You would need to use the Excel Object Model to try to figure that out after you save the attachment using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`. Start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.passwordencryptionfileproperties

Answer (score 0):

I went the route of saving the attachment, but it would be much better if I could retrieve the temporary file path of the attachment and not need to save it. I tried using the GetTemporaryFilePath() method, but the rules of the method made it not work for me. For now, I used xlrd to test if it can open the workbook.

```
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(testfilepath, attachment.filename))
try:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(testfilepath, attachment.filename))  
    attachmentEncryption = 'N'
except: 
    attachmentEncryption = 'Y'
```